# Chaining promises without using 'then'

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, chaining

I have an object (`foo`) that exposes several methods as promises (using jQuery deferred). The way I did it ended up with this kind of code:

```
var foo = createNewFoo();
$.when(foo.method1(arg))
    .then(foo.method2)
    .then(foo.method3);
```

I wish to refactor the below code to be nicer and look like this:

```
var foo = createNewFoo()
    .method1(arg)
    .method2()
    .method3();
```

But I'm not sure how to implement `foo` that it would be possible.

Comment: I think you can do that .. provided every method must return foo object.

Comment: But foo itself isn't a promise, and each method MUST return a promise in order that the next method would be called only after the previous one had beeb resolved.

Comment: not possible. you can't delay a function `return` by somehow waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete

Comment: @JaromandaX definitely possible, if all functions are aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes sure, you just need to extend your `Deferred`s to have these methods:

```
function MyRpc { // if you can use ES2015 - this should be a `class`
  this._deferred = new $.Deferred();
}
// teach it to be a promise
MyRpc.prototype.then = function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
  return this._deferred.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
};

// teach it to be a deferred
MyRpc.protototype.resolve = function(arg) {
  this._deferred.resolve(arg);
};

MyRpc.prototype.reject = function(arg) {
  this._deferred.reject(arg);
};

// define your methods!

MyRpc.prototype.method1 = function(arg) {
  var p = this._deferred.then(function(value) {
    // logic of `method1` from foo.method1 here
  });
  var rpc = new MyRpc(); // our continuation;
  p.then(function(v) { rpc.resolve(v) }, function(e) { rpc.reject(e); });
  return rpc;
};
```

Of course, with a real promise library all this is *a lot* easier than with jQuery's minimal promises.

This would let you do:

```
var rpc = new MyRpc();
rpc.method1(1).method1(2).method1(3); // can also `.then` here
```

I'm not sure it's worth it, but it works.

Comment: Note that the second invocation of `method1` gets both the argument and the resolution value of the previous call in the chain. You can use this to maintain state between calls - this is all probably a mediocre idea that can be better solved with generators or async/await in supporting environments.

Comment: doesn't this mean that method1 is returning a new MyRpc object every time? Sure, the code you've posted may work, but would the third `method1` call have any relationship to the original rpc object? (also, `protototype` typo :p )

Comment: "with a real promise library all this is a lot easier" -
How would you implement this with bluebird, for example?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, just like `.then` returns a new Promise object.

Comment: @NissimHania with bluebird you'd grab your own scoped bluebird copy and just add methods to its prototype - with native promises you'd create a subclass.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum indeed, I'm conversant with how `.then` works thank you ... but the first code sample in the question always uses `foo` - which implies the second code example would somehow be "working" on the same object (`foo`) for each of method1, method2, method3

Comment: @JaromandaX why? This is exactly the sort of interface promises give you. Of course - I could have implemented this with mutations on a mutable object (just changing the `._deferred`) but I think that would be very quirky design. I think this way is a lot nicer but it's entirely up to the person writing the code - now _personally_ I think IO has to be explicit and this might be a little surprising - so I don't like the solution I'm proposing here at all - I merely offered it since it's what was asked.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - why what? why do I interpret the question in a completely different way than you did? Because I can. As there was no substance to method1-3 in the question, I assumed that they would be methods of the **original** foo object - otherwise I see no point in the question at all

Comment: You should make that a promise, not a deferred, and use something like `return new Rpc(p)` in the methods

Comment: @JaromandaX What do you mean no point? This behavior is how promises work - the point is to show a technique and I posted the answer because people claimed it is impossible. Whether or not one would return a `new Rpc` or not is entirely up to them.

Comment: @Bergi In jQuery a deferred is a promise. Note that I use the fact it's a deferred to give a complete solution using jQuery's creation mechanism. I would accept an executor and run _that_ but that would not work with OP's code. For that reason I use the same API the library provides.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I don't mean an executor, I mean that `Rpc` should take the promise itself as an argument. I don't see any reason to implement a deferred interface here, an `Rpc` instance is only resolved from those `then` callback on the new `p`s - which looks like the deferred antipattern to me.

Comment: @Bergi the goal was to provide a jQuery like interface - you can in fact resolve deferreds there before the promise source resolves them for you. I don't _like_ this design choice but I stand by my answer staying consistent with it with the caveat that I say this is complicated and a comment explaining I would do this with subclassing and/or composition myself.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I mean like the code I've now posted as an answer :-) I see you wanted to implement the jQuery deferred interface, but still using that with `then` is a well-known antipattern :-) I think I remember a question where you solved the problem by subclassing Bluebird (and putting the custom methods on the promise), but I can't find it. Do you have a link at hand?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to return a custom object with the methods you need, and let it have a promise for the state instead of the state as properties directly. In every of your methods, you'd need to call `then` on the wrapped promise, and return another instance that wraps a new promise for the new state (method result).

```
function Foo(promise) {
    // make every instance a thenable:
    this.then = promise.then.bind(promise);
    // alternatively store the promise itself as a property and always call this.promise.then
}
function createNewFoo() {
    return new Foo($.when({/* initial state */}));
}
Foo.prototype.method1 = function method1(args) {
    return new Foo(this.then(function(curstate) {
        // method logic here
        // should `return` a new state - or a promise for it
    });
};
Foo.prototype.method2 = …;
```

This is similar to the approaches outlined by Benjamin Gruenbaum and Louy, but with a much simpler implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really aware of Promises (so forgive my example if there is some implementation error) but this is possible using ES6 [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

At this time it's only available on the latest browsers so it might not meet your requirements.

A Proxy allow to add a callback function on each object operations, it mean that you can retrieve the name of the called method to do what you want. 
In your case you want to call `$.when()` with the first promise and call  `.then()` with others as parameter.

```
"use strict";
function createNewFoo(){
    let foo = new Foo();

    let proxy = new Proxy(foo, {

        // @param target : Object on which the operation will be made
        // @param name : property name
        get(target, name) {

            let promise = target[name];

            return function (...args) {

                if (typeof promise === "function"){
                    promise = promise.apply(target, args);
                }
                else if (!(promise instanceof Promise)){
                    throw 'Can\'t handle "'+name+'"';
                }

                // Perform chaining
                if (!target.promise){
                    target.promise = $.when(promise);
                }
                else{
                    target.promise.then(promise);
                }
                return proxy;
            };
        }
    });
    // Storing the Foo instance in the Proxy object, could be implemented in other way.
    proxy._target = foo;
    return proxy;
}
```

Assuming you're using a "class" defined as bellow

```
function Foo(){
    // storing the promise result
    this.promise = null;

    this.method1 = function(arg){ 
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve("1");
        }); 
    }

    this.method2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve("2");
    });
    this.method3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve("3");
    });
}
```

---

You can now use this piece of code to chain your promises

```
var fooProxy = createNewFoo()
    .method1(1)
    .method2()
    .method3();
```

And retrieve the original Foo instance

```
fooProxy._target
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own promise.

```
function MyPromise(resolver) {
  var _promise = new Promise(resolver);
  this.then = function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
    var _p = _promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    return new MyPromise(_p.then.bind(_p));
  };
}
```

Add whatever methods you want...

```
MyPromise.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  return this.then(/*...*/);
};
```

voila!

```
new MyPromise()
  .then(/*...*/).doSomething()
  .then(/*...*/).doSomething(); // etc...
```

*Bonus:*

```
['resolve', 'reject', 'all'].forEach(function(method) {
  MyPromise[method] = function(...args) {
    var promise = Promise[method](...args);
    return new MyPromise(promise.then.bind(promise));
  };
});
```

Also in ES6:

```
class MyPromise {
  constructor(resolver) {
    var _promise = new Promise(resolver);
    this.then = function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
      var _p = _promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
      return new MyPromise(_p.then.bind(_p));
    };
  }
  doSomething() {
    return this.then(/*...*/);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should just pass promises around, not resolvers. Needs less magic :-)

Comment: so the difference with your approach is that you can't go `promise.then().method1()` but you have to `new Foo(promise.then()).method1()`. what I did is subclass `Promise` to make the final syntax cleaner.

Comment: Ah, I see, though that would be easily possible in my solution as well by moving `new Foo` inside the `then`. You're right, it's actually cleaner, but you then should really completely subclass `Promise` by `Object.setPrototypeOf(MyPromise.prototype, Promise.prototype)` and `Object.setPrototypeOf(MyPromise, Promise)`. In which case you actually wouldn't need to write `then`/`resolve`/`reject`/`all` yourself at all.

Comment: Btw, does this work at all? Your `then` method never seems to call `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` anywhere.

Comment: Fixed. thanks for noting that! So according to [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) spec all you need to do is have a "then" method and it's considered a promise. Also subclassing promises the classic way doesn't work in most browsers for some reason. So this is the best approach I could come up with.

Comment: Yeah, most promise implementations don't provide subclassing yet, but in ES6 you will be able to do `class MyPromise extends Promise { doSomething() { return this.then(…); } }`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :-) Now you're exactly at the point where you could simplify to `function MyPromise(_promise) { …` and `return new MyPromise(_p);` :-)

Comment: I know. I thought of it. It's just that it's not something in the standards.

Comment: It's in the standards, it's not in the implementations :-)

Comment: It's not in [the standards](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor). See step 2 of `Promise ( executor )`.

Comment: What do you mean specifically? I guess I misunderstood you.