# Chaining promises without using 'then' with Q library

Tags: javascript, promise, q, chaining

I'm trying to chain Q promises without 'then', so eventually the chain would look like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo
.method1()
.method2()
.method3();
```

How to implement foo's methods so each one is executed once the promise of the previous one is resolved?

This question was marked as exact duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774777/chaining-promises-without-using-then) but I'm trying to implement this using Q lib, not jQuery.

Comment: return `this` keyword in javascript

Comment: Unless Foo is an extension of Q, `this` doesn't really work. The thing that `method1` returns must itself contain a `method2` that calls itself only after `method1` resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are going to gain anything with this.

I suppose that you can do something like this:

```
function Foo() {
  var self = this,
      lastPromise = Promise.resolve();

  var chainPromise = function(method) {
    return function() {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))
      lastPromise = lastPromise.then(function(){
        return method.apply(self, args);
      });
      return self;
    }
  }

  this.method1 = chainPromise(function() {
    // do the method1 stuff
    // return promise
  });

  this.method2 = chainPromise(function() {
    // do the method2 stuff
    // return promise
  });

  // etc...
}
```

Comment: Start with `lastPromise = Promise.resolve()` and avoid the branching

Comment: If you chain onto the `lastPromise`, you're ignoring the `arguments`

Comment: @zevane Thanks!. It works. But to get the result of the previous promise I modified   `lastPromise`, so it looks like: `lastPromise = lastPromise.then(function () { return method.apply(self, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); });`