# Chaining sequential promises in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, promise, q, chaining, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to chain page object methods without using 'then'. Each method returns a promise.

This question was previously marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747256/chaining-promises-without-using-then-with-q-library) but I'm having very specific issue in Nightwatch.

I **already tried** to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747256/chaining-promises-without-using-then-with-q-library) solution, but it breaks the test in case when OtherPage's methods are called before Page's methods - Page's methods are called right away, before methods of OtherPage are executed. I **also tried** [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774777/chaining-promises-without-using-then) proposed solutions, but non of them works.

Here is my page object (pg.js)

```
var Q = require('q');
module.export = {
    elements: {
        someElement: {
            selector: '<h3>'
        }
    },
    commands: [{
        method1: function() {
            var defered = Q.defered();
            setTimeout(function() {
                defered.resolve();
            }, 1000);
            return defered.promise;
        },
        method2: function() {
            var defered = Q.defered();
            setTimeout(function() {
                defered.resolve();
            }, 1000);
            return defered.promise;
        }
    }]
}
```

And this is the test file:

```
module.exports = {
    'Some Test': function (client) {
        var Page = client.page.pg();// methods returning promises
        var OtherPage = client.page.otherpage(); // regular methods

        OtherPage.someMethod();

        // this of course works
        Page
        .method1()
        .then(Page.method2);

        // I'd like to call it this way
        Page
        .method1()
        .method2();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my page object (pg.js) modified, when [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747256/chaining-promises-without-using-then-with-q-library) was applied. Like it's mentioned above, it works, but all of its methods are executed before methods of OtherPage:

```
var PromiseChain = require('./promiseChain');
var promiseChain = new PromiseChain();
var Q = require('q');
module.export = {
    elements: {
        someElement: {
            selector: '<h3>'
        }
    },
    commands: [{
        method1: promiseChain.add(function(arg) {
            var defered = Q.defered();
            setTimeout(function() {
                defered.resolve();
            }, 1000);
            return defered.promise;
        }),
        method2: promiseChain.add(function() {
            var defered = Q.defered();
            setTimeout(function() {
                defered.resolve();
            }, 1000);
            return defered.promise;
        })
    }]
}
```

and here is the promiseChain.js

```
var Q = require('q');
var PromiseChain = function () {
    var lastPromise = Q.resolve();

    this.add = function (method) {
        return function () {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            lastPromise = lastPromise.then(function () {
                return method.apply(this, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            }.bind(this));
            return this;
        };
    };
};

module.exports = PromiseChain;
```

Comment: `I already tried to implement this solution` - can you show how you applied that answer to your previous question to this code, because it doesn't look like you have at all

Comment: Sure, updated the question

Comment: You need to create an *instance* of Page (not a static object with commands), where each instance has its own promise chain, and instead of calling `add` statically when defining the class you need to call it when the respective method of your page object is called.